# How to generate Public key from Public key bytes using RSA in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rsa, x509

I want to create Public key from Public key bytes using RSA and x.509 certificate. After that I want to encrypt data with public key, which will decrypt by java program on server side using private key.

I have tried many libraries to get the solution but I got nil output every-time after encryption.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you generate key in you ios app, it need to some modification before import outside (non-ios) otherwise it will not work and also if you want to use outsider key in your ios app it also need reduce some byte from key, you can find it on web, for import and export  Rsa key I use swiftyRSA , 
https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA

It work fine for me.

Comment: I have downloaded SwiftyRSA and opened in Xcode 7.3 it is showing errors in it. And alsoI am not able to import SwiftyRSA.h file in my app as well. Can you please suggest something here.

Comment: swiftyRSA is now in swift3.0 , so you need to update your xcode at 8 . or use a older version